# Java - Have Loop Repeat if Value is > 10

Tags: java, loops, conditional-statements

first question here.

So for both of these loops I am looking for the user to input a value less than 10 for loop 1 and less than 200 for loop 2. It is almost working to my liking however when a user enters an incorrect number the loop just exits where it should repeat and ask the user for another digit smaller than 10/200.

Any assistance is greatly appreciated.

```
public class Main {

    public static int numberOfStars;

    public static void main(String[ ] args){

                    //ask for number of stars (user-input)
        System.out.println("Enter the number of stars in your constellation");
        Scanner stars = new Scanner(System.in);


            if (numberOfStars <= 10) {
                numberOfStars = stars.nextInt();
            }do{
                System.out.println("The number of stars is : " + numberOfStars);
            } while (numberOfStars <= 10);
   //ask for location of stars (user-input)
        System.out.println("Enter X and Y co-ordinates for your constellation");

        //obj 1
            Scanner myObj = new Scanner(System.in);

            while(myObj.nextInt() <= 200) {
                int location = myObj.nextInt();
                System.out.println("X coordinate 1 is : " + location);
            } do {
            System.out.println("Please enter a Number Less than 200");
        } while (myObj.nextInt() > 200 );
```

Comment: When you check `#nextInt`, it will consume the integer in the input stream. You should also only create a single `Scanner` for `System.in`, and your understanding for a `do/while` loop seems to be off (the `do` is an entirely new branching statement, it does not change based on the preceeding `if` or `while` statements).

Comment: Every time you call `myObj.nextInt()`, input is expected. If you don't store the result of that call anywhere (as you do in `while(myObj.nextInt() <= 200) `), that input is forgotten. Fix that.

Comment: Also please fix your indendation and line breaks, this is confusing to read, mostly to yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You could put all the code in your main mathod in a `while(true)` loop as you are invoking a blocking method. If you succeed (if the value is correct) you can just `break` the main loop (e.g. by marking it with a label). Otherwise `continue` the main loop which makes the input prompt appear again.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).